# Types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I see this example in the illustration of conditional types:

```
type IsNumberType<T> = T extends number ? "yes" : "no";

type Yes = IsNumberType<3>; // type "yes"
type No = IsNumberType<"foo">; // type "no"
```

Why is `"yes"` a type?  Isn't it a value or a string literal?

Comment: It's a literal type: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[String literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) and also Numeric Literals can also be types. This is useful in cases where you only want to allow a string or specific set of strings rather than any arbitrary string.

For example, in CSS the flexbox `align-items` property only takes certain values including `'flex-start'` and `'center'`. It doesn't take any arbitrary value. This allows you to add type safety by specifying the strings that can be used for an `align-items` property.

```
type Styles = { alignItems?: 'center' | 'flex-start' };
const styles: Styles = {};
styles.alignItems = 'cente';  // error
styles.alignItems = 'center'; // ok
```

This is more straightforward than using an enum where you would have to use something like `styles.alignItems = AlignItemStyles.Center` yet it still provides the same amount of type safety.

Answer (score 0):

These are called [String Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types), here the description from the documentation:

> String literal types allow you to specify the exact value a string must have. In practice string literal types combine nicely with union types, type guards, and type aliases. You can use these features together to get enum-like behavior with strings.

[source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types)

Answer (score 0):

Typescript has the concept of a [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types). Any constant aka literal, can be used as a type :

```
    let foo:'foo' = 'foo'
```

The only valid value for the variable `foo` is the literal string `'foo'`. By themselves they are not necessarily useful, but put them together with a union and you get a variable with a limited set of possible values.

```
 let fooBar : 'foo' |'bar' = 'bar'
```

Put them together with unions of interfaces and you get [discriminated unions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/discriminated-unions.html).

String literal types are also used in mapped types and `keyof` also returns a union of string literal types representing the keys of a type.

Once you get to know then they turn out to be incredibly useful :-)